# AttributeError when using multiprocessing inside a class that is based on an abstract class

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I'm trying to define a plot class `MyPlot`, based on the abstract class `GenericPlot`, that creates 3 Matplotlib figures in parallel using pathos multiprocessing:

```
from attr import define
from abc import abstractmethod
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import dill

dill.settings['recurse'] = True

def generate_array(fig):
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    canvas.draw()
    figure_array = np.asarray(canvas.buffer_rgba())
    return figure_array

def parallel_process_function(args):
    function, data = args
    return function(*data)


@define
class GenericPlot():
    x: np.ndarray

    @abstractmethod
    def plot_series(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def generate_figures(self):
        ...
    
    def plot_figures(self):
        self.plot_series()
        return self.generate_figures()


@define(slots=False)
class MyPlot(GenericPlot):

    def plot_series(self):
        self.series1 = np.sin(self.x)
        self.series2 = np.cos(self.x)
        self.series3 = np.tan(self.x)

    def create_figure1(self, a):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(self.series1*a)
        axes.plot(self.series2)
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure2(self, a):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(self.series2*a)
        axes.plot(self.series3)
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure3(self, a):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(self.series3*a)
        axes.plot(self.series1)
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure_array(self, create_figure_method, a):
        fig = create_figure_method(a)
        figure_array = generate_array(fig)
        return fig, figure_array

    def parallel_create_figure_array(self, create_figure_method, a):
        return self.create_figure_array(create_figure_method, a)

    def generate_figures(self):
        
        pool = ProcessPool(nodes=3)
        functions = [self.parallel_create_figure_array, self.parallel_create_figure_array, self.parallel_create_figure_array]
        create_figure_methods = [self.create_figure1, self.create_figure2, self.create_figure3]
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        data = [(method, a) for method, a in zip(create_figure_methods, a)]
        results = pool.map(parallel_process_function, zip(functions, data))
        figures, image_arrays = zip(*results)
        return figures, image_arrays

my_plotter = MyPlot(x=np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
figures, image_arrays = my_plotter.plot_figures()
```

The code runs successfully *without* abstract class, i.e. if I only define

```
@define(slots=False)
class MyPlot(GenericPlot):
    x: np.ndarray

    ...
```

and then run

```
my_plotter = MyPlot(x=np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
my_plotter.plot_series()
figures, image_arrays = my_plotter.generate_figures()
```

but as soon as I attempt to use the abstract class (yes, I need it even though in this example it is not necessary), the `pool.map` function throws `AttributeError: 'MyPlot' object has no attribute 'series1'`.

Any idea why the multiprocessing pool doesn't correctly parse the class attributes?

I'm very new to the use of multiprocessing, so I may be missing something very obvious...
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to pass abstract classes attributes to multiprocessing, but I managed to at least work around the problem by dumping `MyPlot` attributes to a dictionary and passing them to the plotting functions.

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

...

attr_dict = AttrDict(vars(self))
```

Full example:

```
from attr import define
from abc import abstractmethod
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import dill


dill.settings['recurse'] = True

def generate_array(fig):
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    canvas.draw()
    figure_array = np.asarray(canvas.buffer_rgba())
    return figure_array

def parallel_process_function(args):
    function, data = args
    return function(*data)


class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self


@define
class GenericPlot():
    x: np.ndarray

    @abstractmethod
    def plot_series(self):
        ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def generate_figures(self):
        ...
    
    def plot_figures(self):
        self.plot_series()
        return self.generate_figures()


@define(slots=False)
class MyPlot(GenericPlot):

    def plot_series(self):
        self.series1 = np.sin(self.x)
        self.series2 = np.cos(self.x)
        self.series3 = np.tan(self.x)

    def create_figure1(self, attr_dict):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series1"])
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series2"])
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure2(self, attr_dict):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series2"])
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series3"])
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure3(self, attr_dict):
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 3))
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series3"])
        axes.plot(attr_dict["series1"])
        plt.close("all")
        return fig

    def create_figure_array(self, create_figure_method, a):
        fig = create_figure_method(a)
        figure_array = generate_array(fig)
        return fig, figure_array

    def parallel_create_figure_array(self, create_figure_method, a):
        return self.create_figure_array(create_figure_method, a)

    def generate_figures(self):
        pool = ProcessPool(nodes=3)
        functions = [self.parallel_create_figure_array, self.parallel_create_figure_array, self.parallel_create_figure_array]
        create_figure_methods = [self.create_figure1, self.create_figure2, self.create_figure3]
        attr_dict = AttrDict(vars(self))
        data = [(method, attr_dict) for method in create_figure_methods]
        results = pool.map(parallel_process_function, zip(functions, data))
        figures, image_arrays = zip(*results)
        return figures, image_arrays

my_plotter = MyPlot(x=np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
figures, image_arrays = my_plotter.plot_figures()
```

It does seem a bit "hacky" and it adds in my opinion an unnecessary passage, so I hope someone comes up with a better, cleaner solution...